# Passing variable of type alias into function that requires pointer to underlying type

Tags: pointers, go, reference

I have my custom type alias (*with methods*) defined as:

```
type AwsRegion string
```

Then I want to pass variable of this type to another legacy (*not under my control*) function, that accepts pointer to string (*pointer to underlying type*):

```
func main() {
    var region AwsRegion = "us-west-2"
    f(&region) // How to properly cast AwsRegion type here?
}

func f(s *string) {
    fmt.Println(*s) // just an example
}
```

And of course I can't do that, error message states:

```
cannot use &region (type *AwsRegion) as type *string in argument to f
```

How to properly cast `region` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand why you need to define an `AwsRegion` type if your input takes a `string` as an input.

Use `f(s *AwsRegion)`

**EDIT** - as per your comments

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

type AwsRegion string

var region AwsRegion

func main() {
    flag.StringVar((*string)(&region), "region", "us-west-1", "AWS region to use")
    flag.Parse()
}

func f(s *string) {
    fmt.Println(*s) // just an example
}
```

Comment: That `f()` function is out of my control. It's basically, simplified signature of 
`flag.StringVar(p *string,.....)`
function. So, need to satisfy contract.
And i have variable of type `AwsRegion` (with my methods attached) that I want to pass into that `flag.StringVar()` function.

Actually, I solved this issue by implementing for my `AwsRegion` type all methods from `flag.Value` interface -- but that's a different story.

Answer (score 4):

The `region` variable should be casted to the `pointer to string` type.
But due to `*` operator precedence, this should be done this way:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type AwsRegion string


func main() {
    var region AwsRegion = "us-west-2"
    f((*string)(&region)) // parentheses required!
}

func f(s *string) {
    fmt.Println(*s)
}
```

Link to [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vFdt_JQghm)